# Read and update multiple documents with a single query in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following type of data saved in my database (MongoDB)

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5935359293ed1f37e52785fe"),
    "_class" : "com.example.bean.UserActivity",
    "appId" : NumberLong(1234),
    "uId" : "9999",
    "itemId" : "10024",
    "timestamp" : "2017-06-05T10:42:26.896Z",
    "status" : 0
}
```

**Usecase**

I want to **read and update my all document** in a database whose `status =` `0`

I trying to solve my use-case using this query

```
    db.userActivity.findAndModify(
        { 
          query: { 'appId' : 1234, 'status' : 0},
          update: { $inc: { 'status': 1 } } 
       });
```

It worked **but it only modified one document**.

My use-case is to find all document and update their status?

**Note:** Using this below query I can update multiple documents but I want to read as well as update multiple documents using a single query.

Is is possible in MongoDB?

```
db.userActivity.update({ 'appId' : 1234, 'status' : 0}, {$set: { 'status': 1 }}, {multi: true})
```

Or is there any **alternative way** to achieve it.

**Edit 1**:  **Complete use-case**

I want to read all documents in my database having a particular `appId` and `status` = 0 and set `status` = 1 after reading them

- Status 0 = unread
- Status 1 = read

After this I want to write them in file so that I can upload it to a file server.

I have a worker (a separate thread) who on periodic bases let say (after every 24 hrs) read all documents from MongoDB and create a file of it.

Why I am maintaining status is so to avoid duplicate read by my worker.

Comment: Just so you know. Most of the people who would actually vote to close also have the privilege to see deleted posts. You could have just cleaned up your old post to make it clearer. But this is exactly the same post, without a thing changed. You need to reword this and explain what you are actually doing. Mention the file creation.

Comment: Ok, I will explain everything in my edit, sir, I am really stuck, please have a look after 1 minute

Comment: As stated in the docs, `findAndModify` only updates 1 document (at most). If your use case is really *to find all document and update their status* you should be fine with `update`

Comment: Just trying to help you get the point across. And also maybe get you to understand that when you delete a question you delete the conversation. Then new people come along and start the conversation back on all the things already covered. Like what just happened.

Comment: @NeilLunn sure, I will take a note of this

Comment: @Ruben using update I can update many document but I won't be able to read them, I want to also read them